# Property 'firestore' does not exist on type 'FirebaseNamespace' with Firebase v7.15.1

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I upgrade from `firebase` v7.14.3 to v7.15.1 I get the following build error / typescript error:

> TS2339: Property 'firestore' does not exist on type 'FirebaseNamespace'.

I import and use Firestore as following:

```
import {firebase} from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/firestore';

const firestore: firebase.firestore.Firestore = firebase.firestore();
```

=> `firebase.firestore()` is my issue.

I have probably missed the CHANGELOG, any help on how to migrate this appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have always imported Firebase client SDKs in TypeScript like this:

```
npm install firebase
```

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const firestore = firebase.firestore()
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you Doug. No idea why my above imports ever worked out ;)

Comment: I get `It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK. When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.` warning when imported like this. Any idea?

Comment: https://github.com/dalenguyen/firebase-functions-helper/blob/HEAD/docs/firestore.md#firestore--firebase-functions-helper

Comment: @Doug Stevenson i am getting this type of error after following the same method you have send. Property 'firestore' does not exist on type 'typeof

Comment: @kazim ali me too :(

Comment: Same for me! @DougStevenson

Comment: PS. Take a look here! https://stackoverflow.com/a/69489577/11127383

Answer (score 13):

For newer versions it's:

```js
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const config = {
  apiKey: ...,
  authDomain: ...,
  projectId: ...,
  storageBucket: ...,
  messagingSenderId: ...,
  appId: ...
};

const app = initializeApp(config);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

Comment: Took me a while to find this!

Answer (score 6):

For me worked to update the import from

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
```

to

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Tnx