# Why do I get firebase namespace errors after upgrading to Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I have upgraded my project from Angular 10 -> 11.

After I have done that, I get errors like this:

[image]

I have imported firebase like this:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/database';
import '@firebase/firestore';
import '@firebase/auth';
import '@firebase/analytics';
import '@firebase/functions';
import '@firebase/storage';
```

Example where I get an error:

```
const firestoreDocRefs: firebase.firestore.DocumentReference[] = [];
```

and

```
analyticsRef: firebase.analytics.Analytics;
```

What has changed when going from Angular 10 -> 11 and how can I get the firebase namespace to work for me again?

Comment: This does help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62415105/property-firestore-does-not-exist-on-type-firebasenamespace-with-firebase-v7 ?

Comment: @MikeOne That was how I used to do it, but now it generates more errors

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting I found that this works:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/analytics';
import 'firebase/functions';
import 'firebase/storage';
```