# Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof import..." firebase/auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = firebase.auth();
const database = firebase.database();
```

This is my code but it gives me this error

> Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof import("[project path]/node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app/index")'.ts(2339)
> any

Comment: Check this, could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67649316/property-auth-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-import-home-kartik-desktop-ecom

Comment: It wasn't helpful

Answer (score 69):

They updated the imports with v9. The fix is easy, just update to:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

Here's the [relevant section of the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat)

Answer (score 12):

I think this will work, even I faced the same problem
Update imports to v9 compat

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/database';

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = firebase.auth();
const database = firebase.database();
```

Before: version 8

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

After: version 9 compat
v9 compat packages are API compatible with v8 code

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

Answer (score 3):

For firebase v10 (it can work for other versions) use the following code: (worked for me)

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = firebase.default.auth();
const database = firebase.default.database();
```

Answer (score 1):

works for me
`import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'; import 'firebase/compat/auth'; import 'firebase/compat/firestore';`

relevant section of the docs

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31385753)

Answer (score 0):

Just add

from this
firebase.auth();

to this
firebase.default.auth();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).